# (HTML, CSS) Refused to load the script

Tags: html, css, materialize

Help me, please! I was deploying html website into Heroku, but i got this error...

```
Refused to load the script 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

here is my my footer.hbs file:

```
<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"
></script>
<script src="/app.js"></script>
```

and here is my my head.hbs file:

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta http-equiv="con">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/index.css">
  <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
```</div>
````

Answer (score 1):

CSP is a security feature that helps to protect web applications from various attacks, such as cross-site scripting (XSS), by specifying which sources of content are allowed to be loaded on a page.

To resolve this issue, you need to update your CSP to include the appropriate "script-src" directive with the sources that your script is being loaded from. You can do this by adding a Content-Security-Policy HTTP header to your server's response.

add this header with your script

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' https://example.com;
```

Comment: sorry i don't know how to do it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).